# Sqlite dbContext.SaveChanges() is throwing "SQL logic error or missing database"

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to connect to Sqlite data with Asp.Net vNext application. 
everything was working fine but when i tried to create add data the following error was thrown 
"SQL logic error or missing database" .

```
db.Tests.ToList(); is returning the data properly but when i do

Test tt = new Test { Name1 = "PP" };
db.Tests.Add(tt);
db.SaveChanges(); it throws the above error.
```

I have check if the db file is in read only mode which was not the case. And I also was manually able to insert t
he data in the table.

```
My Test Class
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] // Even after removing this property i am     getting the same error
public long ID { get; set; }

[Required]
public string Name1 { get; set; }
```

i have following thing in proj.json

```
 "EntityFramework": "7.0.0-alpha4",
 "EntityFramework.SQLite": "7.0.0-alpha4",
 "EntityFramework.InMemory": "7.0.0-alpha4"

  My ConnectionString
   "Data": {
   "DefaultConnection": {
    "ConnectionString":           "Filename=C:\Users\Adarsh\Desktop\WebApplication2\src\WebApplication2\Data\Db4.sqlite"
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in "EntityFramework": "7.0.0-alpha4" . Basically you cant use both SQlite and SQlServer on entity framework it will not work.

```
        services.AddEntityFramework()
                .AddSQLite()
                .AddSqlServer()
```

We should only use either SQLite or SqlServer only then this will work.